# How to get listen flutter widget rendering updates /change?

Tags: flutter, widget, video-processing, event-listener, flutter-animation

I want to experiment with making videos with flutter, I already have an idea, namely by making the widget an image, but I'm confused when there is a controller / setState update,
how do i listen for updates of all widget changes ?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply set a breakpoint inside the `build()` method of your widget, or you can simply set a `print()`:

```
/*...*/
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 print("build");
/*...*/ 
 }
```

whenever a rebuild will be done to your widget, the `build()` will be called, and so the `print()` will be called